# Network request failed on Android device using fetch

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I've got error "Network request failed" when using fetch in React Native on Android emulator/real device. The code is below:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/response', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          Accept: "aplication/json;charset=UTF-8",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({name: "abc", email: "something@gmail.com"}),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

          alert('response object:' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));

          if(responseJson.valid === true){
              // do something

          }

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      });

    });
```

I've tried to fix it by adding "app.use(cors());" on express server. This fix works when I simulate on web but still fails on emulator or real device.

Comment: did you try to make ///android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"// in android manfiest

Comment: I use Expo to deploy the app

Answer (score 3):

You got 2 options:

- Either implement https for your api endpoint as Neelam mentioned
- Or add clearTextTraffic true in your AndroidManifest as Abd mentioned here is how you can do that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option does not work, I'm using Expo for app deployment so there is not AndroidManifest file but an app.json configuration file instead

Answer (score 2):

React native is not worked when you fetch localhost url means instead of localhost you supposed to put an IP address their to make sure that devices are within a network. Just Replace localhost with your IP address. And make sure to connect your mobile with same wifi or network.

```
fetch('http://yourIPaddress:3000/response', {
      method: 'POST',
```

Ask if any query.

Comment: Thank. Yes, I connected my phone to the machine via USB, changing localhost to my machine IP address but nothing worked!

Comment: Check your api call from POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

use secure server links https, it should work for you

Comment: I've found a solution. Just need to replace 'localhost' by '10.0.2.2'' for Android emulator then it worked.